# How to use toggle switch with django boolean field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have a work_experience model which contains "is_working" field which is true when a user is still working at a company.
On front end I'm using a toggle switch and I want to change the boolean field value "is_working" on click.
What should be the logic to use toggle in django?

**Toggle switch**

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>Currently working here?</label>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
class Work_Experience(models.Model):
    job_title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    company         = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    exp_start_date  = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    exp_end_date    = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_working      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a bad idea to give `null=True` parameter for `CharField`.

If you want to change the boolean field value `is_working` on click, you need to use **Jquery**.

I created an app named `toggle`, so you need to replace it with your app's name.

here is the full code

**urls.py**::

```
from django.urls import path
from toggle.views import home, toggle

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home),
    path('toggle/', toggle),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    w, created = Work_Experience.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    return render(request,'home.html', {'workexperiance': w})

from django.http import HttpResponse
from toggle.models import Work_Experience
def toggle(request):
    w = Work_Experience.objects.get(id=request.POST['id'])
    w.is_working = request.POST['isworking'] == 'true'
    w.save()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

**home.html:**

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>Currently working here?</label>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="{{workexperiance.is_working}}">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> <!-- Import Jquery Here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkbox').change(function() {
        $.post("/toggle/", {
            id: '{{workexperiance.id}}', 
            isworking: this.checked, 
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' 
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

run: `./manage.py runserver` and visit: `http://localhost:8000`

when you click the **Currently working here?** check box, will instantly
change the boolean field value "is_working".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the page being refreshed, here is how I will do it:

**views.py:**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Work_Experience
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def toggle_status(request,pk):
    status = Work_Experience.objects.get(id=pk)
    status.is_working^=True
    status.save()
    return redirect(reverse_lazy('HTML.html'))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import toggle_status

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    ...
    ...
    path('toggle-status/<int:pk>/', toggle_status, name='toggle-status'),
]
```

**HTML.html**

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
  <label>Currently working here?</label>
  <a href="{% url 'toggle-status' task.id %}">
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
```