# How to change the boolean value of a form field when the toggle button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

What would be the corresponding jQuery function or Ajax function to change these toggle values so that if the toggle switch is on the value would be changed to True?

I took a reference from : [How to use toggle switch with django boolean field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671266/how-to-use-toggle-switch-with-django-boolean-field)

But, If I select or not select the toggle button, the value always remains False.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class CsvForm(forms.Form):
    shipping_us = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    shipping_europe = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    shipping_asia = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
def submit(request):
    csv_form = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_form = CsvForm(request.POST)
        if csv_form.is_valid():
           shipping_us = csv_form.cleaned_data['shipping_us']
           shipping_europe = csv_form.cleaned_data['shipping_europe']
           shipping_asia = csv_form.cleaned_data['shipping_asia']
           context= {'shipping_us': shipping_us,'shipping_europe': shipping_europe,'shipping_asia': shipping_asia,'csv_form':csv_form.}
           return render(request,'submit.html', context)
        else:
           csv_form = CSVForm()
           context = {'csv_form':csv_form}
           return render(request,'submit.html',context)
    else:
      return render(request,'submit.html')
```

index.html

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="{% url 'submit'%}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}

<div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Shipping Options/US</div>
                           
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name ="shipping_us" value="{{ shipping_us }}">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                                
                              </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Shipping Options/Europe</div>
                            
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name ="shipping_europe" value="{{ shipping_europe }}">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>

                                
                              </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Shipping Options/Asia</div>
                           
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="shipping_asia" value="{{ shipping_asia }}">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                                
                              </label>
                        </div>

</form>
```

submit.html

```
 <p>{{ shipping_us }}</p>
 <p>{{ shipping_europe}}</p>
 <p>{{ shipping_asia }}</p>
```

The submit.html displays

```
False
False
False
```

What would be the corresponding jQuery function or Ajax function to change these toggle values so that if the toggle switch is on the value would be changed to True?

What I've tried is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkbox').change(function() {
            $.post("", {
                 
                shipping_us: this.checked, 
                shipping_europe:this.checked,
                shipping_asia:this.checked,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' 
            });
        });
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on your issue .

Comment: The issue is simple, if the toggle switch is selected, it should turn into True.

Comment: What you have tried so far to address this issue..?

Comment: You should be setting the `checked` attribute and not the `value` on the checkbox inputs

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate and show in code

Comment: I have edited my jQuery script but not working

Comment: @Sumithran I have written what I've tried