# How to create user status active deactivate toggle button in Django?

Tags: django

I want something like this in my Django .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74L1Y.jpg)
Can anyone tell me how should I code in html template and views.py ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the boolean field value status on click, you need to use Jquery.

I created an app named toggle, so you need to replace it with your app's name and is_working with your status button.

here is the full code

**urls.py::**

```
from django.urls import path
from toggle.views import home, toggle

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home),
    path('toggle/', toggle),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    w, created = Work_Experience.objects.get_or_create(id=1)
    return render(request,'home.html', {'workexperiance': w})

from django.http import HttpResponse
from toggle.models import Work_Experience
def toggle(request):
    w = Work_Experience.objects.get(id=request.POST['id'])
    w.is_working = request.POST['isworking'] == 'true'
    w.save()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

**home.html:**

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <label>Currently working here?</label>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="{{workexperiance.is_working}}">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> <!-- Import Jquery Here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkbox').change(function() {
        $.post("/toggle/", {
            id: '{{workexperiance.id}}', 
            isworking: this.checked, 
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' 
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

run: ./manage.py runserver and visit: http://localhost:8000

when you click the Currently working here? check box, will instantly change the boolean field value "is_working".

reference to originally answered question :
[Originally answered link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55672111/8401179)